# node.js with ES6 modules, Typescript and Winston: "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'winston'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, winston

#### I am trying to get Winston working in node.js (v13.11.0) with ES6 modules enabled and typescript, but without success so far:

My code is (in `src/lib/logging.ts`):

```js
import * as logger from 'winston';
// ...
```

Firstly I did:

```sh
$ npm install --save winston
```

Which has added it to `dependencies` section as expected:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    ...
}
```

But when I start the app, I get the **following error**:

> src/lib/logging.ts:2:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'winston'.
>
> 2 import * as logger from 'winston';

Then I tried what for some other dependencies worked:

```sh
$ npm install --save-dev @types/winston
npm WARN deprecated @types/winston@2.4.4: This is a stub types definition. 
winston provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
```

This added an **older** version to `devDependencies`, which seems useless:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    ...
}
```

And when I start the application I get the **same error** as listed above.

Comment: since you are running node try to do the import as follows 
const winston = require('winston');

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but it seems like a hack, given that I am using ES6 modules.

Comment: great i will add it to the answers below in case someone else need it he/she can see it properly

Answer (score 3):

The solution mentioned by @HadiMir will work. However, since you want it to be working with ES6, here's an example - [Morgan logging with ESM](https://github.com/karan0405/todo/blob/main/config.js).

Also you need to mention "type" as module in your package.json to mention that you will be using ESM import style. If you do not want this, the alternate would be to use file with the ".mjs" extension.

`"type": "module",`